# SoapUI Property Transfer: How to extract items from XML using xpath?

Tags: xml, rest, xpath, soapui

I'm running SoapUI on my machine to check some RESTful webservices.

The server gives me the following structure

```
<Response xmlns="http://localhost/filter">
    <data>
          <e>
              <ticket>
                  <reason>Bla bla bla</reason>
                  <number>98765</number>
              </ticket>
              <number>1234</number>
              <content>Some stuff here</content>
          </e>
          <e>
              <number>23455</number>
              <content>Some stuff here 2</content>
          </e>
    </data>
</Response>
```

I want to run some testcases, but I need the regular number (here: 1234, 23455).

```
//*:number[1]
```

Will give me only the ticket number (here: 98765). When running

```
//*:content[1]
```

It brings the phrase 'Some stuff here', so it seems to work, because it picks the correct xml structure.
But why is SoapUI sending me the wrong number?

I tried with a namespace, but it didn't work either. On top of that, a SO member said in another topic, a namespace is not mandatory.

Edit:
Now, it works.
I tried
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23585499/soapui-how-to-get-the-list-of-nodes-by-using-local-name-in-xpath-expression) solutions by albciff.
Using

```
(//*[local-name()='number'])[1]
```

instead of

```
//*[local-name()='number'][1]
```

will work. The statement still needs brackets.

Comment: it's nice that my other answers helps you `:)`, however will be great if you put your last question edit as an answer in order to help others to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//*:number[1]` or `//*[local-name() = 'number'][1]` selects *all* `number` elements in your input document that are are the first child of their parent element:

```
<number>98765</number>
-----------------------
<number>1234</number>
-----------------------
<number>23455</number>
```

I suspect that your XPath environment only returns the *first* result node if there are several. To select the other numbers, you could use

```
//*:e/*:number[1]
```

or

```
//*[local-name() = 'e']/*[local-name() = 'number'][1]
```

and the result will be (individual results separated by `-------`):

```
<number>1234</number>
-----------------------
<number>23455</number>
```

Again, most likely your XPath engine will only return the first of those results.

Comment: @user3417078 Perhaps you could say _what_ first number you get? It is **impossible** to get `98765` with `//*[local-name() = 'e']/*[local-name() = 'number'][1]`.

Comment: I only get '98765' and it doesn't change, when running your other solutions.

Comment: @user3417078 As I said, that's impossible. Either you are not applying the correct XPath expression, or your input document is different from what you have shown, or your implementation of XPath is not compliant and does not respect the XPath specification.

Comment: Okay. I will try to find some other solutions like Groovy Script. Thanks.

Comment: @user3417078 You are welcome. Sorry I could not be more help.